# Mongoose "this.model is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is how I defined my Schema & Schema methods.

```
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 const ItemSchema = new Schema({
        type:String,
        brand:String,
    description:String,
        model:String,
        price:Number,
    createdAt:{type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


ItemSchema.statics.findBrand = function(brand, callback){ 
    // this == item
    return this.find({brand: brand}, callback);
}

ItemSchema.statics.findType = function(type, callback){
    return this.find({type: type}, callback);
}

ItemSchema.methods.findSameBrand = function(cb){
    return this.model("Item").find({brand: this.brand}, cb);
}

var Item = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema);
```

adding items to the database and using the methods.

```
Item.remove({}, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    Item.create(itemData, function(err, items) {
        if(err) console.error(err);

        Item.findOne( {type: "Mouse"}, function(err, mouse){

            console.log(mouse);

            mouse.findSameBrand( (err, items) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);

                //any code

            db.close( () => {
                console.log("connection closed");
            });

        });

    });

});
```

The console.log(mouse) prints the first mouse document it found

```
{ _id: 598907ecbf5ac40b24346028,
  type: 'Mouse',
  brand: 'Corsair',
  description: '2',
  model: 'G104',
  price: 8000,
}
```

Yet I am getting an error that this.models is not a function.

> this.model is not a function.
>   at model.ItemSchema.methods.brandFind >(/Users/sean/ApplicationsDevelopment/sandbox.js:39:21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined 'model' as string when you create new Schema.
Just delete `model:String,`

> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: Saved me from a lot of headache. Thanks!