# Call a function from different controller in express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a function in questionController

```
show: function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    questionModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, question) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error when getting question.',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!question) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'No such question'
            });
        }
        //var user = userController.show(); 
        return res.render("questions/question", question);
    });
},
```

And i want to somehow use the function from userController so that i would get the user that posted the question. This is the function i want to use:

```
show: function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    userModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error when getting user.',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'No such user'
            });
        }
        return res.json(user);
    });
},
```

Or is there a better way i can achieve this? I should note, i usually use relationship databases.

Code i wish to achieve (in a more elegant way if possible):

```
//this is a questionController function
show: function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    questionModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, question) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error when getting question.',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!question) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'No such question'
            });
        }
        var userID = question.userID;
        //this is a function i copied from userController that i would like to call from userController so it would be a bit more elegant
        userModel.findOne({_id: userID}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error when getting user.',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'No such user'
                });
            }
            question.username = user.username;
            return res.render("questions/question", question);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: hey there, why are you using the notation  `show: `? are you working with Express, I am not familar with this notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understood what you want, please, let me know if got it right.

Try this:

**Answer**: you must use `mySchema.methods`

In the same file you are defining your User schema, before `mongoose.model(...)` (i.e., before you compile the model):

```
UserSchema.methods.doYourThing(id){     
     //--------------------------------------------------------
    //this is just the function you had to copy, and want to use   
    this.model("User").findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error when getting user.',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'No such user'
            });
        }
        return res.json(user);
    });
},

    }
```

Then, when you need to use it, you could do something like:

```
const user= mongoose.model("User")
..........
user.doYourThing(userid);
```

I have done the code from my head (i.e., I did not test it), and I do not have information about your schema; you will need to fix my typos and/or adapt to your code; I hope you get the idea.

**References**

- [Mongoose "this.model is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557696/mongoose-this-model-is-not-a-function)
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

Answer (score 0):

You should try to import the controller and then call the function;

```
const userController = require("userController");

userController.show();
```

Comment: but i want to save it to a variable

Comment: "but i want to save it to a variable " can you explain better what you want? maybe if you post the problem you are trying to solve. can you show the schemas?

Comment: @JorgePires i have edited the code so that it achieves what i want, but i feel like im not doing it correctly. I copied userModel.findone from userController, but i want to call that method not copy it